# total variation for closed set zero if measure is zero on closed subsets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a complex borel measure on $\Omega$, $|\mu|$ its total variation and $A \subseteq \Omega$ a closed set s.t. for each closed set $B\subseteq A$ we have $\mu(A)=0$. Now does it hold that $|\mu|(A)=0$? I think yes, as it would trivially hold if $\mu(C)=0$ for all measurable subsets of $A$ and the closed sets generate the measurable sets, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. We can consider the system of subsets of the ambient space for which the intersection with $A$ has measure zero. We show that this system is a Dynkin-System and contains the closed intervals. Hence, as the closed intervals are closed under finite intersections, the system contains the sigma algebra generated by the closed set, which are already the borel sets.